# Rainbow Array (Android)

Tags: android, arrays, colors

I have an array that will contain an unknown number of elements. I would like to create an array of equal length that corresponds to that array, only this new array will contain colors. Is it possible to programatically assign colors to the new array in such a way that if you were to line up the colors of indexes 0 thru the length of the array, you would have a rainbow? I am clueless as to how to even go about calculating which color to put at each index, and any guidance would be very very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: correct, a one-to-one correspondence. each color will correspond uniquely with an element in the other array

Comment: Step 1. map (0-100)% to a color.  Step 2. map each of (0-n)/n to a color.  Step 3. map x to n (to discard extremes).  The first step's the hardest; try HSV space.